# Sum of the total count (Running total based on User Count) - Is it possible?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to do the cumulative count for the users first time access the web page.

Table looks like,

```
UserID , Initial Access Date

    100, 2019-05-10 
    200, 2019-05-20 
    100, 2019-05-21 
    100, 2019-05-25 
    200, 2019-05-30 
    300, 2019-06-01
```

Current Expression:

```
Cumulative Total =
CALCULATE (
    DISTINCTCOUNT ( [USERID] ),
    FILTER (
        ALLSELECTED ( TABLE ),
        [INITIAL ACCESS DATE] <= MAX ( [INITIAL ACCESS DATE] )
    )
)
```

This only returns cumulative total count, How would I get the running total based on this count of Users.

Expected Results:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got it working without creating extra columns or measures,

```
Cumulative Total =

CALCULATE (
    SUMX (
        Table,
        IF ( DISTINCTCOUNT ( Table[UserID] ) > 0, 1, 0 )
    ),
    FILTER (
        ALLSELECTED ( Table ),
        Table[InitialAccessDate]
            <= MAX ( Table[InitialAccessDate] )
    )
)
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

1 - Upload your Fact table in Power Bi

2 - Create a Date Table

```
Date = CALENDARAUTO()
```

Then

```
Year = Year('Date'[Date])
Month = MONTH('Date'[Date])
YEAR_MONTH = VALUE('Date'[Year])*100+VALUE('Date'[Month])
```

3 - Set relationships

4 - You can compute a set of two measures :

First

```
InitialAccess = 
VAR InitialAccessInCurrentPeriod = 
DISTINCTCOUNT(Fact_T[UserID ])
RETURN
InitialAccessInCurrentPeriod
```

Then :

```
InitialAccessCumulated = 
VAR MaxDateInPeriod = MAX('Date'[Date])                      // Retrieve the last date in current filter context
VAR StartingDate = MINX(ALLSELECTED('Date');[Year])          // Retrieve the lowest year selected on slicer
RETURN
CALCULATE(
    [InitialAccess];                                        // Compute the number of initial access
    FILTER(                                                 // In a nex filter context where all the dates
        ALL('Date');                                        // Equal or superior to the lowest date selected
        'Date'[Year]>=StartingDate
        &&
        'Date'[Date]<= MaxDateInPeriod                       // Until the last date visible in the current row context
    )
)
```

You can see the final result here :

[image]

I have added to row to your fact table to have several years 
Here is the Fact table used :

```
UserID   Initial Access Date
50  12/12/2018
100 10/05/2019
200 20/05/2019
100 21/05/2019
100 25/05/2019
200 30/05/2019
300 01/06/2019
400 04/02/2020
```

Comment: I like the way you detailed (Commented) it. :)